# Yii the SQL query error based on Criteria

Tags: sql, yii, criteria

I want to search for some model events while filtering them both on time and related users basis.
Wnen i do it in the Grid it works fine. Yet, when i additionally input some data in grid inputs to search on Event's other attributes the ajax responce goes:
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.
[image]
The 'IN condition' (shown in query) is added into the criteria:

```
 $newCriteria = new CDbCriteria;        
 // get events id (several ) of current user
 $events = $model->getEvents($currentUser);
 // add the condition into criteria;  't' being the model table alias
 if ($events) $newCriteria->addInCondition('t.Id', $events); 
 // merge with criteria from the model (DocEvents)
 $newCriteria->mergeWith($model->criteria());

 $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('DocEvents', array(
        'criteria'=>$newCriteria,//$model->criteria(), 
    ));

 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,   
'filter'=>$model,'columns'=>array(
    'Id',
    'Subject',
    'EventTypeId',
    'Begin',
    'End',
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
    ),
  ),
));
```

The criteria in model file:

```
 public function criteria()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('Id',$this->Id);
    $criteria->compare('Subject',$this->Subject,true);
    $criteria->compare('Notes',$this->Notes,true);
    $criteria->compare('Place',$this->Place,true);
    $criteria->compare('EventTypeId',$this->EventTypeId,true);
    $criteria->compare('Percentage',$this->Percentage);
    $criteria->compare('ReflectInCalendar',$this->ReflectInCalendar);
    $criteria->compare('ParentId',$this->ParentId);
    $criteria->compare('Priority',$this->Priority);
    $criteria->compare('StatusId',$this->StatusId);
    $criteria->compare('Comment',$this->Comment,true);
    $criteria->compare('PlanHours',$this->PlanHours);
    $criteria->compare('Tags',$this->Tags,true);

    $conditions=array();
    if ($this->Begin) $conditions[] = 'Begin >= "' . $this->Begin . '" ';
    if ($this->End) $conditions[] = 'End <= "' . $this->End . '" ';
    $criteria->condition = implode(' AND ', $conditions);

    return $criteria;
}
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Turn on the CWebLogRoute and set 'enableProfiling' and 'enableParamLoggin' to 'true' in your db component in your config file to see which parameters are bounded.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/nl/topics.logging

Comment: $events is the array containing the id's of events pertaining to the $currentUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails when you input additional data is because at least one of the `compare` lines is being used, which ends up constructing part of the criteria's condition, along with binding a parameter for that piece of the condition (aka where clause).

However, at the end of your `criteria()` method, you overwrite the condition with the following line:

```
$criteria->condition = implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

This results in having bound parameters, but all your tokens have been overwritten.

As such, use

```
$criteria->addCondition(implode(' AND ', $conditions));
```

instead to keep from overwriting the where clause that you had already created.

Or, even more simply, use the following instead of imploding your `$conditions` array.

```
if ($this->Begin) $criteria->addCondition('Begin >= "' . $this->Begin . '" ';
if ($this->End) $criteria->addCondition('End <= "' . $this->End . '" ');
```